# AJAX not showing up in Firebug Console

Tags: jquery, ajax

Disclaimer: not sure this is WordPress related or not.

I'm following a [simple tutorial](http://pippinsplugins.com/process-ajax-requests-correctly-in-wordpress-plugins/?doing_wp_cron=1338820330#comment-12549) to check if AJAX works in my WordPress localhost.

My ajax-test.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $(".ajax-link").click( function(){
        var data = {
            action: 'test_response',
            post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
        };
        $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                                                       alert(response);
                                                       });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In my plugin, I add the script to the wp_print_scripts() and add the processing function:

```
function test_ajax_load_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script("ajax-test", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'ajax-test.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script('ajax-test', 'the_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ) );
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'test_ajax_load_scripts');

function text_ajax_process_request(){ 
    if(isset($_POST["post_var"])){
        $response = $_POST["post_var"];
        echo $response;
        die();
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_test_response', 'test_ajax_process_request');
```

I get the link output with the href="#" and I click it and it brings me to the top of the page. I check Firebug and I can confirm that the ajax-test.js is loaded in the header. There is nothing in the console.

How else can I debug why the alert is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event wire-up function needs an [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in it:

```
$(".ajax-link").click( function(e){ //<--------- e
    e.preventDefault(); //<-------- preventDefault()   
    var data = {
        action: 'test_response',
        post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
    };
    $.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });        
});
```

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the "return false;" with preventDefault too.

Answer (score 0):

If you returned false and the page still jumped to top, you are getting a javascript error. More than likely the `$.post` is failing. Try adding an error callback to the `$.post` to get more information.

```
$.post(...).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments)
});
```

Another possibility is that the click handler isn't even being reached. In that case, make sure that the selector is correct and that the element exists on the page when the code is ran. If the element is added by ajax or javascript, you will need this code to run AFTER that element has been added, or you'll need to attach the event using event delegation with `.on` or `.delegate`

```
$(document).on("click",".ajax-link",function(){...});
```